# How do I take the values from a csv file to be used in a query string?

Tags: csv, request

In STEP 1 of this code I am able to get the values from the CSV file, I am trying to complete STEP 2, where I use the values from STEP 1 for leadid and disposition, to be placed inside the querystring. How can I accomplish this?

#STEP 1

## read csv file to get values for lead_id and disposition

## importing module

```
from pandas import *
```

## reading CSV file

```
data = read_csv("names.csv")
```

## converting column data to list

```
leadid = data['lead_id'].tolist()
disposition = data['disposition'].tolist()
```

#STEP 2

## i need to place the values for leadid and disposition into the querystring for "leadID" and "disposition"

```
import requests

url = "https://api.leadspedia.com/core/v2/leads/updateLead.do"

querystring = {"leadID":"**INSERT LIST VALUE HERE**","disposition":"**INSERT LIST VALUE HERE**"}

payload = ""
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Authorization': "XYZ"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: see: [docs](https://developer.leadspedia.com/docs/core-api/b3A6MzE4MjY4MDk-update-lead-status) (and try the `Send API-request` button)

Comment: the api works fine, i just need to get values out of a csv file and do bulk updates to step 2 @Luuk